# How to mix HTML and C# Code in MVC3 with Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to display a list of items that should toggle a class for styling purposes. The idea is to create a foreach loop that will cycle through all the `myObj` in the Model.

I tried the following code which does not work (because I'm doing it wrong)

```
@{ int i = 2;
   foreach(var myObj in Model)
   {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            <div class="class1">
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="class2">
        }
        Html.Partial(...);
        </div>
         i += 1;
   }     
}
```

What is the proper way to accomplish this?

**Update**

I also tried the following code that, although compiles, does not render any HTML code within (and I'm sure there are objects in Model).

```
@{ int i = 2;
   foreach(var myObj in Model)
   {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            @:<div class="class1">
        }
        else
        {
            @:<div class="class2">
        }
        Html.Partial(...);
        @:</div>

        i += 1;
   }

}
```

This is the partial class being called

```
<div class="class">
    <div class="class2">
        @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(var))
        {
            @var2
        }
        else
        {
            @var
        }
    </div>
    <div class="class3">
        @var3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class4">
    <p>var4</p>
    <ul class="class5">
        <li>element1</li>
        <li>element2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm sorry I can't post the actual names and variables.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how it doesn't work?  Do you get output?  Do you get exceptions?

Comment: To update: Can we see the partial view and the call to it please?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let's start with improving your code.

- Improvement step 1:

  ```
  @foreach(var myObj in Model.Select((model, index) => new { model, index }))
  {
      <div class="class@(myObj.index % 2 == 0 ? "1" : "2")">
          @Html.Partial("_Foo", myObj.model)
      </div>
  }
  ```
- Improvement Step 2 (using a custom HTML helper for the class):

  ```
  @foreach(var myObj in Model.Select((model, index) => new { model, index }))
  {
      <div class="@Html.MyClass(myObj.index)">
          @Html.Partial("_Foo", myObj.model)
      </div>
  }
  ```

  where MyClass is defined like this:

  ```
  public static string MyClass(this HtmlHelper html, int index)
  {
      return (index % 2 == 0) ? "class1" : "class2";
  }
  ```
- Improvement step 3 which is the state of the art (using [Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx)):

  ```
  @Model.List(
      @<div class="@item.MyClass">
          @Html.Partial("_Foo", @item.Model)
      </div>
  )
  ```

  where the `List` extension method looks like this:

  ```
  public class ModelHolder<T>
  {
      public T Model { get; set; }
      public string MyClass { get; set; }
  }

  public static class RazorExtensions
  {
      public static HelperResult List<T>(
          this IEnumerable<T> items,
          Func<ModelHolder<T>, HelperResult> template
      )
      {
          return new HelperResult(writer =>
          {
              foreach (var item in items.Select((model, index) => new { model, index }))
              {
                  var myClass = item.index % 2 == 0 ? "class1" : "class2";
                  template(new ModelHolder<T> { Model = item.model, MyClass = myClass }).WriteTo(writer);
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```

I vote for improvement number 3 which is far better and more concise than the original foreach loop.

Comment: I went for improvement number 1 and it worked. For future reference, I did NOT test the rest.

Comment: I believe is always good to look back and consult old questions... At that time this answer looked so complicated I didn't even attempt the other improvements, now it all seems to obvious... Thanks again Darin, this was a very good answer.

Answer (score 19):

You need to prefix the lines with non-well-formed tags with `@:` to prevent Razor from trying to parse the tags.
[Details](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

You may be sure there are objects in some model - but not your model : )
the following sample code derived directly from yours works just fine:

```
@{ int i = 2;
   string[] list = new string[] {"a","b","c","d"};
   foreach(var myObj in list)
   {
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            @:<div class="class1">
        }
        else
        {
            @:<div class="class2">
        }
        //Html.Partial(...);
        @:</div>
         i += 1;
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `@Html.Partial(...)` to render the result to the page.

Calling `Html.Partial` returns a `HelperResult` with the partial view, but doesn't actually render it.